# Memory Error in Python using gensim.utils.simple_preprocess

Tags: python, memory, gensim, word2vec

I am a beginner with gensim word2vec, and I am encountering a memory error when preparing text for training the model. I am using Python 3.8.8. I have about 900,000 text files in 12 different folders. I was thinking I should send all text documents through gensim.utils.simple_preprocess, and then I'd have a list of lists for the model. After going through about 150,000 documents, I received a memory error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "word2vec_part1.py", line 58, in <module>
    documents = list(read_input(paths))
  File "word2vec_part1.py", line 39, in read_input
    myfile = infile.read()
MemoryError
```

Is there a way to fix this memory issue? I included the code I am using below. I am new to Python, word2vec, and stackoverflow, so I apologize if my question is poorly worded or if this is a dumb question! Thank you for your time!

```
# imports and logging

import gensim 
import logging
import os
import os.path
import glob


logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

# define function

def read_input(inputs):

    # logging info
    logging.info("reading files")

    # set working directories and load files into a list
    for path in inputs:
        os.chdir(path)
        read_files=glob.glob("*.txt") 
        # preprocess and counting
        for i, file in enumerate(read_files):
            if(i%10000==0):
                logging.info("read {0} reviews".format(i))
            # preprocessing and return a list of words
            with open(file, "rb") as infile:
                myfile = infile.read()
                yield gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(myfile)


# create a list of all file paths
paths = [#here is a list of file paths]

# call function
documents = list(read_input(paths))
logging.info("done reading files!!")
print(len(documents))
print(documents[1])

# training word2vec model
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec (documents, size=150, window=10, min_count=2)
model.train(documents,total_examples=len(documents),epochs=10)
model.save("word2vec.model")

# look up top 6 words similar to 'law'
w1 = ["law"]
model.wv.most_similar (positive=w1,topn=6)

logging.info("done!!!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that attempting to hold all the documents in a `list` in memory requires more RAM than your system has. (Perhaps also: one of the files is gigantic. What's the largest single file?)

It's not necessary to hold all docs in memory. Gensim's `Word2Vec` (& other algorithms) can almost always accept any Python *iterable* object - one that can iterate over its contents one-by-one, repeatedly, even if they're coming from some other back-end. This typically uses far less RAM.

The leader of the Gensim project has a useful post about iterables that could help you adapt your `read_input()` function into a wrapper class that can re-iterate over the files repeatedly:

https://rare-technologies.com/data-streaming-in-python-generators-iterators-iterables/

Two other notes:

(1) `simple_preprocess()` isn't especially sophisticated, and you may want to do your own tokenization instead; but:

(2) If you re-tokenize on every iteration, especially if your tokenization does anything sophisticated or uses regular-expressions, you're doing a lot of redundant re-tokenizing of the same texts, which is likely to be a bottleneck in your training. So in fact you might want to just use your `read_input()` not to stuff all rokenized docs into a list, but write them to a new file, post-tokenization, one-document to a line and all tokens separated by single spaces. Then, a utility class like Gensim's [`LineSentence`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.LineSentence) can provide the iterable-wrapper for feeding that almost-fully-ready file to `Word2Vec`.